# Scrollbar doesn't appear in a ListView?

Tags: c#, listview

Simple problem. I add columns through code to a `ListView` component.

```
myList.Columns.Add("Title", 32);
```

Parameters are as follow : (Title, Width)

The problem is when column are out of the Horizontal View, scrollbar doesn't appear. It only appears when I click on the `ListView`, like as if it then realize it should have a Scrollbar.

How can I make sure it appears when I add the column and the Horizontal View is not wide enough to cover every column?

Comment: @vipersassassin it is not the same as I want it to appear when needed, not when there is no need.

Comment: From that answer you can put in limitation on when visible is set (i.e. visible = (Width > myList.Size.Width)? true : false;)

Comment: @vipersassassin thanks a lot!!